# Video with width: 100% and custom height:

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm trying to set my video with 100% width but not 100% height, instead I need to set a custom height.

My HTML:

```
<div id="video-player">
   <video width="1905px" height="800" autoplay >
      <source src="video/earth.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
video {
  width: 1905px    !important;
  height: 800px   !important;

}
```

It sets a 100% Width, but it also sets a 100% Heightm overpassing the height I need.

Any solution ?

Comment: Wouldn't you just set your video's width to 100% its container? Whatever height is the final property would be set. Also, wouldn't you want to keep a ratio proportion to your video instead of putting in some guessed height?

Answer (score 0):

```
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove width and height attribute from video opening tag. Now write in css,

```
video{
 width:100%;
}
```

This will works on all devices including mobiles and tabs.